# Uso de bucles en Java, imprimir los días del año

Tags: java

Me mandaron un trabajo practico de mi facultad, lo pude resolver pero me parece que no es lo que busca el profesor.

El enunciado es este:

> Sabiendo que el 1/1/2021 fue viernes, imprimir todos los días del año 2021 de la siguiente manera:
> viernes 1 de enero de 2021
> hasta
> viernes 31 de diciembre de 2021

---

Y para hacer eso tengo que usar bucles, estuve pensando y googleando lo mas que pude pero no se me cae una idea de como expresar la lógica **T.T** lo único que se me ocurrió lo adjunto a mi pregunta.

Estoy recién aprendiendo a programar con java y en la facultad vimos: *switch, if else y bucles*.

```
public class Tp7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int e = 1; e < 29; e += 7) {
            System.out.println("viernes " + e + " de enero de 2021");
            System.out.println("sabado " + (e + 1) + " de enero de 2021");
            System.out.println("domingo " + (e + 2) + " de enero de 2021");
            System.out.println("lunes " + (e + 3) + " de enero de 2021");
            System.out.println("martes " + (e + 4) + " de enero de 2021");
            System.out.println("miercoles " + (e + 5) + " de enero de 2021");
            System.out.println("jueves " + (e + 6) + " de enero de 2021");


        }
        System.out.println("viernes 29 de enero de 2021");
        System.out.println("sabado 30 de enero de 2021");
        System.out.println("domingo 31 de enero de 2021");


        for (int f = 1; f <= 22; f += 7) {
            System.out.println("lunes " + f + " de febrero de 2021");
            System.out.println("martes " + (f + 1) + " de febrero de 2021");
            System.out.println("miercoles " + (f + 2) + " de febrero de 2021");
            System.out.println("jueves " + (f + 3) + " de febrero de 2021");
            System.out.println("viernes " + (f + 4) + " de febrero de 2021");
            System.out.println("sabado " + (f + 5) + " de febrero de 2021");
            System.out.println("domingo " + (f + 6) + " de febrero de 2021");

        }

        for(int m = 1; m < 29; m += 7){
            System.out.println("lunes " + m + " de marzo de 2021");
            System.out.println("martes " + (m + 1) + " de marzo de 2021");
            System.out.println("miercoles " + (m + 2) + " de marzo de 2021");
            System.out.println("jueves " + (m + 3) + " de marzo de 2021");
            System.out.println("viernes " + (m + 4) + " de marzo de 2021");
            System.out.println("sabado " + (m + 5) + " de marzo de 2021");
            System.out.println("domingo " + (m + 6) + " de marzo de 2021");
        }
        System.out.println("lunes 29 de marzo de 2021");
        System.out.println("martes 30 de marzo de 2021");
        System.out.println("miercoles 31 de marzo de 2021");

        for(int a = 1; a < 29; a += 7){
            System.out.println("jueves " + a + " de abril de 2021");
            System.out.println("viernes " + (a + 1) + " de abril de 2021");
            System.out.println("sabado " + (a + 2) + " de abril de 2021");
            System.out.println("domingo" + (a + 3) + " de abril de 2021");
            System.out.println("lunes " + (a + 4) + " de abril de 2021");
            System.out.println("martes " + (a + 5) + " de abril de 2021");
            System.out.println("miercoles " + (a + 6) + " de abril de 2021");
        }
        System.out.println("jueves 29 de abril de 2021");
        System.out.println("viernes 30 de abril de 2021");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre una solución con mucho menos código.

Para empezar definiría arrays con las cadenas con los nombres de los meses y los días de la semana, porque lo vas a repetir muchas veces y va a servir para ir recorriéndolos:

```
String[] semana = {"viernes", "sabado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miercoles", "jueves"};
String[] meses = { "ene", "feb", "mar", "abr", "may", "jun", "jul", "ago", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dic"};
```

También definiría un array con los días que tiene cada mes:

```
int[] diasmes = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

Y un índice `diasemana` que empezará en 0 y se incrementará hasta llegar a la longitud del array que guarda los nombres de los días de la semana. Con ese índice podremos recuperar el nombre de cada día:

```
int diasemana = 0;
//Recorremos todos los meses que hay en el array de meses:    
for( int i = 0; i < meses.length; i++) {
    //Recorremos los días que tenga ese mes, que están en diasmes, cada mes 28, 30 o 31 días.    
    for( int j = 0; j < diasmes[i]; j++) {
        //Cuando el día de la semana haya llegado al último, tenemos que volver a empezar con el primero.
        if( diasemana == semana.length)
            diasemana = 0;
        //j + 1 es el día del mes, meses[i] es el nombre del mes y semana[diasemana] el nombre del día de la semana.
        System.out.println( j + 1 + " de " + meses[i] + ", " + semana[diasemana ]);
        //Una vez usado un día de la semana, pasamos al siguiente.
        diasemana++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dos apuntes: (1) el índice del día se puede incrementar restringiendo el módulo a 7, con lo cual sobraría el bloque if -es decir en lugar de sem++ poner sem = (sem + 1) % 7; (2) creo que llamas de dos formas distintas a ese índice del día de la semana: diasemana y sem.

Comment: Cierto ambas cosas. La primera, según gustos, me resulta más fácil de entender a mi manera cuando tienes que volver a revisar el código pasado un tiempo. Pero tu idea también valdría. Y la segunda ya la he corregido, un despiste mío. Gracias por el aporte.

Comment: De nada. Puede que tengas razón y sea según gustos pero en cuanto a volver pasado un tiempo, yo soy partidario de cuantas menos líneas de código que revisar, mejor. Salud!

Answer (score 3):

Una forma simple de imprimir un rango de fechas es utilizar un formato de fecha junto a una variable de fecha he ir incrementando el día en 1, de esta forma simplificaremos la complejidad del Código ya que no tendremos que manejar si el mes es de 28, 29, 30 o 31 ni variables extras:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ImprimirDias {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Definimos el formato de fecha a utilizar
        DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy");
        // Creamos las variables con el rango de fechas a imprimir
        LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1);
        LocalDate fechaFinal = LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 31);

        // Evaluamos que la fecha inicial sea anterior a fecha final,
        // como se quiere incluir la fecha final en los datos a mostrar se le suma un día.
        while (fecha.isBefore(fechaFinal.plusDays(1))){
            // Pasamos el formato de fecha deseado
            System.out.println(fecha.format(formato));
            // Se suma un día a la fecha para evaluar en el bucle si aun está en rango.
            fecha = fecha.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Para el formato: "EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy"

EEEE: muestra el nombre del día completo "lunes, martes, miércoles, etc".

d: muestra el día del mes.

MMMM: muestra el nombre del mes completo "enero, febrero, etc"

yyyy: muestra el año en formato de 4 digitos.

'de': lo que esta entre comillas es texto que se agrega al formato.

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
viernes 1 de enero de 2021
sábado 2 de enero de 2021
domingo 3 de enero de 2021
lunes 4 de enero de 2021
martes 5 de enero de 2021
miércoles 6 de enero de 2021
jueves 7 de enero de 2021
viernes 8 de enero de 2021
sábado 9 de enero de 2021
domingo 10 de enero de 2021
lunes 11 de enero de 2021
.
.
.

viernes 31 de diciembre de 2021
```

> Tambien se puede utilizar `DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);` pero decidí
> crear el formato de fecha para enseñar una forma más flexible.
>
> Otro punto a tener en cuenta es que este método toma en cuenta el
> idioma del `PC` donde de ejecuta, para definir el idioma para los
> textos se debe utilizar `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Comment: Solamente como comentario sería mejor aumentarle a la fecha final un día antes del ciclo while. De lo contrario estarías repitiendo esa operación por cada repetición del ciclo.

Comment: Si lo pensé, pero al ser algo didáctico opte por dejarlo en el while para la explicación, pero lo que dices es correcto.

Comment: El resultado final es el esperado pero creo que no es lo que pedía el profesor. ¿En qué momento has tenido en cuenta que el primer día del año fue viernes? Dato clave. La idea era, creo, implementarlo solo con concatenación de cadenas, bucles y arrays, sin emplear clases más complejas como LocalDate y DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Primero el enunciado solo confirma que la fecha `1/1/2021 fue viernes`  no se esta inventando la fecha, sabiendo esto no necesito validar que el 1/1/2021 es viernes, segundo el enunciado solo dice que sea en bucle y no coloca más restricciones, si ahi dijese que necesita ser concatenado y uso de array pues quien realiza la pregunta lo especifiqué para colocar una variante o que teniendo las repuestas que se le han dado que abarcan multiples formas pueda crear su propio proceso que seria aun mejor.