# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de fecha de todos los campos tipo Date de una lista en Java 8?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, date-format

Tengo el siguiente servicio que consulta a una base de datos por rangos de fecha (inicial y final), y me regresa una lista en la cual hay varios campos tipo Date, que me gustaría cambiar en formato `ddmmyyyy`, o bien que se pinte por ejemplo `Miercoles, 28 de Enero del 2021`.

¿Cómo podría realizar ese cambio? ¿Tendría que agregarse en la clase `serviceImpl` la lógica?
¿Cómo identificar esos campos que son tipo `Date` y darle ese tipo de formato? porque actualmente pinta la fecha en el formato `2021-06-11T05:00:00.000+00:00`.

Controller

```
@RestController
public class ConsultarValoresController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ConsultarValoresService  consultarValoresService  
    
    @GetMapping()
    public List<ValoresDTO> listar(@RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaInicio") Integer fechaInicio, @RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaFin") Integer fechaFin){
        return cconsultarValoresService.consultarValores(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
    }
```

Service impl

```
@Service
public class ConsultarValoresServiceImpl implements ConsultarValoresService{

    @Autowired
    private ConsultarValoresRepository consultarValoresRepository 
    
    @Override
    public List<ValoresDTO> consultarValores(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) {
        return consultarValoresRepository.consultarValoresBd(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
    }
```

Modelo

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_VALORES")
public class ValoresDto implements Serializable {
        
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8878842006433138183L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="IDREGISTRO")
    private Integer idRegistro;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="RANGO")
    private Integer rango
    
    @Column(name="FECHAREGISTRO")
    private Date fechaRegistro
    
    @Column(name="FECHAPLAZO")
    private Date fechaPlazo;
    
    @Column(name="FECHAPLAZO1")
    private Date fechaPlazo1;
    
    @Column(name="FECHAPLAZO2")
    private Date fechaPlazo2;

    @Column(name="FECHAPLAZO3")
    private Date fechaPlazo3;

    @Column(name="TASA")
    private Double tasa

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como spring-boot utiliza `jackson` como la librería por defecto para serializar los objetos a Json debes de utilizar la anotacion `@JsonFormat` del paquete `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;` además ten cuidado con el formato `ddmmyyyy` porque `mm` es de minutos y `MM` es de mes,te dejo algunos ejemplo de como utilizar la anotación con los formatos:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_VALORES")
public class ValoresDto implements Serializable {
// Código omitido    

    @Column(name="FECHAREGISTRO")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "ddMMyyyy")
    private Date fechaRegistro
    
    @Column(name="FECHAPLAZO")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "ddMMyyyy")
    private Date fechaPlazo;
    
    @Column(name="FECHAPLAZO1")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy")
    private Date fechaPlazo1;
    
    @Column(name="FECHAPLAZO2")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy")
    private Date fechaPlazo2;

    @Column(name="FECHAPLAZO3")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date fechaPlazo3;

// Código omitido


}
```

> Esta es una repuesta donde explico el formato `EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy`
> [Uso de bucles en Java, imprimir los días del año](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/454792/uso-de-bucles-en-java-imprimir-los-d%c3%adas-del-a%c3%b1o/454831#454831)

Comment: ya lo probe de esa manera pero no hace nada, no lo muestra en ese formato